# How to join a dictionary with same key as df index as a new column with values from the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

I have the following data:

A dictionary `dict` with a `key: value` structure as `tuple(str, str,): list[float]`

```
{
    ('A', 'B'): [0, 1, 2, 3],
    ('A', 'C'): [4, 5, 6, 7],
    ('A', 'D'): [8, 9, 10, 11],
    ('B', 'A'): [12, 13, 14, 15]
}
```

And a pandas dataframe `df` with an index of 2 columns that correspond to the keys in the dictionary:

```
df.set_index("first", "second"]).sort_index()
print(df.head(4))
==============================================
                                        tokens
first           second  
 A              B                          166  
                C                          128  
                D                          160  
 B              A                          475
```

I want to create a new column, `numbers` in `df` with the values provided from `dict`, whose key corresponds with an index row in `df`. The example result would be:

```
print(df.head(4))
========================================================================
                                        tokens          numbers
first           second  
 A              B                          166          [0, 1, 2, 3]
                C                          128          [4, 5, 6, 7]  
                D                          160          [8, 9, 10, 11]  
 B              A                          475          [12, 13, 14, 15]
```

What is the best way to go about this? Keep performance in mind, as this dataframe may be 10-100k rows long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a series from the dict, and then assign:

```
df['numbers'] = pd.Series(d)
```

Or map the index:

```
df['numbers'] = df.index.map(d)
```

Output:

```
              tokens           numbers
first second                          
A     B          166      [0, 1, 2, 3]
      C          128      [4, 5, 6, 7]
      D          160    [8, 9, 10, 11]
B     A          475  [12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Series then concatenate it with dataframe:

```
sr = pd.Series(d, name='numbers')
out = pd.concat([df, sr], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
     tokens           numbers
A B     166      [0, 1, 2, 3]
  C     128      [4, 5, 6, 7]
  D     160    [8, 9, 10, 11]
B A     475  [12, 13, 14, 15]
```